# ASP.NET WebControl Proxy, hosted on SharePoint, that will interact with Java application...?

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net, html, sharepoint

I'm in charge to integrate a JAVA application into a SharePoint environment. There are some page flows i need to import. 
A flow consists of certain pages that interact with each other based on certain actions. A form POST, hyperlink click (URL/URL with query parameters, ..)

I'm trying to create some sort of proxy.

Something like:

- an iframe
- proxy based on HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse
- something with ajax and java script

... that will interact with the Java application and that will spit out the returned html, and will also catch the new action that needs to be send to the java application.

At the moment I'm already thinking about one major issue: in ASP.NET everything is already inside one huge html form. So just rendering the java html inside the page will give problems when there is one or more html forms on the java page.

If any one has some tips, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

BCS is most preferred way to integrate other applications.

You can read this article for some more option
http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services

SPService uses JQuery ( AJAX )
http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's "Sharepoint Web Services", if it's not too much of a hassle, is probably the best way to go:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx

There are, however, alternatives.  For example:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sl-SI/sharepoint2010programming/thread/4629653f-fa26-439f-bb63-db691cc406e0

'Hope that helps!

PS:
"David's IT Blog" has some interesting entries you might wish to check out:

- http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/
- http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/sharepoint-web-services-3-things-to-consider-before-coding-in-java/

PPS:
iFrames?  Ugh.  Resist the temptation - don't do it ;)!